# How can I convert old Warhammer Army Book content to 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, conversion, warhammer

I am using some old [Warhammer Army Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warhammer_Army_Book) for storyline and flavor inspiration for my D&D game, but I am also noticing there are weapons and spells for possible conversion in these books. How do you convert items from Warhammer Army Book stats to D&D 3.5?

Army Books often include conversion information for 2nd edition Warhammer RPG rules, but I do not have the main Warhammer Fantasy RPG book, just some Army Books made available to me.

Comment: What edition books are we talking about here?

Answer (score 3):

### There is no set conversion process.

The Warhammer Fantasy RPG is not a 3.5 product, and is not very similar to it either. There is no fixed conversion process, nor guidelines I am aware of, and I would be extremely skeptical of anything which claimed to do so in any systematic way.

DnD 3.5 is somewhat precariously balanced to start with. You are likely best off starting with the inspiration in the army books and writing up any game effects from scratch. You would need to spend just as much attention on making sure the output of any conversion was appropriate to your game as you will writing it up whole-cloth.

Sorry there's no easier answer. :/